# How to implement Asynchronous Task / Observer in F# / .Net 5.0

Tags: f#, observable, reactive-programming

So what I want to do is click on a button in Winforms ( C# ), and it would run a task in a library written in F#.  I am using .Net 5.0.  I need it to run on a separate thread so it doesn't make the form freeze.  It seems like there are a few directions I could go in - but I am leaning more towards a functional programming approach - trying to move away from OOP where possible.

I am thinking:

- send the background worker object into the library function ( doesn't seem like a good approach )
- Implement observer pattern. Something like http://www.fssnip.net/7j/title/Observer-pattern
- Use Reactive Extensions? https://github.com/dotnet/reactive
- Something else?

I'm not sure what direction people would take here.  I have read somewhere that if you use events there is an issue with memory leaking.

Comment: The answer is too broad to be answered - it really depends what exactly do you need to do.

Comment: Have a look at [Elmish.WPF](https://github.com/elmish/Elmish.WPF/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md)